# Convert High voltage output ( 15V ) to 5 V

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, pcb, pcb-design, logic-level

I want to use : DSD 70 Dual Channel Hall Effect Speed Sensor and integrate it with an MCU ( arduino ) atmega , so I have to convert the output of the sensor to 5V to be able to read it by the MCU.
Any one can suggest a chip to do that ?

The sensor is : [https://www.te.com/global-en/product-CAT-SPS0020.html#:~:text=The%20DSD%2070%20series%20speed,a%20frequency%20of%200%20Hz](https://www.te.com/global-en/product-CAT-SPS0020.html#:%7E:text=The%20DSD%2070%20series%20speed,a%20frequency%20of%200%20Hz).

and the output spec is :
2 phase shifted square wave signals, minimum edge shift with an involute gear
wheel: minimal phase shift of 20° for gear of the defined module between output 1
(S1) and output 2 (S2)

- Push-pull outputs : Imax = ± 30 mA
  o Output voltage HI (for I = Imax): UHI > Usupply - 1.5 V
  o Output voltage LO (for I = Imax): ULO < 1.5 V

Comment: are you finished with this Q and A now?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this configuration: -

[image]

Your output voltage will be from about 1 volt to about 13 or 14 volts so, if you use a 20 kohm to 10 kohm potential divider like this (on each output signal): -

[image]

The output voltage will be operate between about 0.3 volts to about 4.5 volts and be compatible with most MCU inputs. The divider will also present an output impedance of about 6 kohm so if the supply voltage (15 volts) to the sensor were raised a bit, the output impedance would prevent a serious over-voltage event happening to the MCU input by substantially current limiting the current into the MCU pin.